# How do I make kate the default text editor in gnome?

Tags: gnome, kate

I prefer the gnome desktop to KDE - but I prefer the Kate text editor to gedit - but gedit is the default in gnome.

How do I set it so that the default application when I double-click a file is Kate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [this](http://djcraven5.blogspot.com/2008/02/changing-default-text-editor-in-gnome.html) little tutorial. Or, if you want a simpler way, just right click on the file and  choose to open with the application you want.

Comment: Thanks Alex - I now about the right click option, but sometimes I just mindlessly double click on the file and would prefer it to load in Kate

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to change my default editor to emacsclient (which opens a file in the current emacs session, running in server mode).  The problem was, I didn't have an emacsclient.desktop file anywhere.  It worked when I just adapted the /usr/share/applications/emacs23.desktop file and put it in ~/.local/share/applications/emacsclient.desktop

This was based on the description at  http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg12557.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Alex this works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

create a file `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` with this content:

```
[Default Applications]
application/x-perl=kate.desktop
text/plain=kate.desktop
text/x-chdr=kate.desktop
text/x-csrc=kate.desktop
text/x-dtd=kate.desktop
text/x-java=kate.desktop
text/mathml=kate.desktop
text/x-python=kate.desktop
text/x-sql=kate.desktop
```

Create missing kate.desktop with a copy:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop /usr/share/applications/kate.desktop
```

In the copied file, replace `gedit` with `kate` i.e. with vim `:%s/gedit/kate`

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful. I use it to accomplish the same thing as the tutorial alex linked. Should work on Ubnutu Karmic to Lucid.

```
~/$ cat bin/upkateprefs
#!/bin/bash
#Changes all new/existing gedit editor preferences to kate

#change existing preferences
sed -i "s/gedit/kde4-kate/" ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

#add new file type preferences
cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list|grep gedit|sed "s/gedit/kde4-kate/" >> ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

#remove duplicates
sort -u ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list -o ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

It's not perfect in that it will bring in a duplicate mime type line if you have more than just gedit in your existing preferences line. It will also break the file format if you have more sections than just [Added Associations]. Perhaps a wizard will come along and come up with a better script.

Answer (score 0):

I am in Ubuntu 20.04 and I needed to edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list` so that `text/plain=org.kde.kate.desktop` was in the `[Default Applications]` block.

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=org.kde.kate.desktop
```